# How to add wired connection to Network in 18.04?

Tags: networking, server, 18.04

I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 installed, to which I added Ubuntu Desktop to it, I'm trying to setup Screen Sharing on it, but it says it has no connection to set it up on, I checked the Network section of settings and there is no Wired connection on it, also the top bar says Wired Unmanaged connected and it won't let me set it up.

What can I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Once the wired connection is set up, is it your intention to run the server with an attached monitor and a desktop or without a monitor; i.e. headless?

Answer (score 0):

I get this after running that command:

```
 # This file is generated from information provided by
 # the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
 # To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
 # /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
 # network: {config: disabled} network:
     ethernets:
         enp2s0f0:
             addresses:
             - 192.168.1.10/24
             gateway4: 192.168.1.1
             nameservers:
                 addresses:
                 - 192.168.1.60
                 - 192.168.1.50
                 search: [example.com]
            optional: true
     version: 2
```